# Azure Remote Tables And Entity Framework: Join two tables

Tags: azure, entity-framework

I read through some answeres here, but they dont seem to apply my usecase.

I have a a few tables running on Azure Mobile Apps Backend, I can query them just fine with entity framework.
I know that I could do two queries and just join my results on client side, but Im sure there is a better way.

My issue is however, that I have a table inside my middleware, and then a dataservice with a remote model class that I use to query data from my service. This is how I would query a User by Email:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserItem>?> GetItemByEmail(string email)
{
    await InitializeAsync();
    try
    {
        return await _table.GetAsyncItems().Where(x => x.Email == email).ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The issue however is, that this only works on the one table (UserItemTable) which is referencend in `_table`.

Now there is no reference to a second table with which I wanna join.
Maybe this isnt the right place to do this inside the RemoteTable Controllers?

Any help would be appreciated.